# Message from pandas 2.1.0

Tags: python, pandas

I just updated to pandas 2.1.0 and got two warning messages:

```
/var/folders/zh/p5f3ptld0pq2zys9y_ls3hcw0000gn/T/ipykernel_89388/1515832451.py:122: FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame concatenation with empty or all-NA entries is deprecated. In a future version, this will no longer exclude empty or all-NA columns when determining the result dtypes. To retain the old behavior, exclude the relevant entries before the concat operation.
  df = pd.concat(dfs)
/Users/jacques/opt/anaconda3/envs/data/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py:373: FutureWarning: is_sparse is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Check `isinstance(dtype, pd.SparseDtype)` instead.
  if _pandas_api.is_sparse(col):
```

What should I do not to have these two messages?

Comment: Update your code accordingly, so when these features are implemented and you (or your users) upgrade to that version of pandas; the code will continue to function as expected.  Otherwise, you could be distributing / using code which is known to break in time.

Comment: I have similar problem with XGBoost calling the warning. It seems that the devs are aware of the problem. Since there is no need to create a separate Stack question for that, and this one here popped up when I googled the error I just leave reference to XGBoost issue here, in the comment: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/9425

Comment: @StuSztukowski it litterally tells you to make a pull request on the Pyarrow library ?

Answer (score 5):

For me it was pyarrow making the outdated call, similar to the question. Look at your error message that's throwing the exception:

```shell
.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py:373: FutureWarning: is_sparse is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Check `isinstance(dtype, pd.SparseDtype)` instead.
  if _pandas_api.is_sparse(col):
```

Unless it's your own code that's using the outdated specification, you'll see that the stack trace is pointing to the offending package making the call. Note that in my case and in the case of original question, pyarrow is implicated here.

So now run:

```shell
pip install --upgrade pyarrow
```

I was on 11.0.0, upgraded to 13.0.0 and the warning went away.

Comment: Did not work for me, see my comment below the question.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by upgrading some dependant libraries as well, specifically scikit-learn, which called the offending, deprecated function in an earlier version.

pip install --upgrade scikit-learn

Comment: "fuction" is a classic. At 17 min 07 secs in [episode 50 of the (original) Stack Overflow podcast, 2009-04-21](http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode50-2009.04.21.mp3) (with [Steve Yegge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Yegge)).

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, what caused this for me was I just installed Scikit-Learn, among other things, in a new Python 3.10 environment using conda as follows:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

But this gave me version 1.2.2 and `conda update scikit-learn` would not work.

Looking at the [installation instructions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) they recommend installing from the condo-forge channel, so I did the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

Now I have version 1.3.2 and the warnings have gone.